# How does pointer address type checking work?

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior

I am trying to understand if there is an implementation for checking the type of a variable at a specific address in C when dealing with pointers.

Assume we have the following code:

```
Car car1; // variable of type Car in memory at address 0x100
Fruit fruit1; // variable of type Fruit at address 0x104
Car *pCar1; // pointer of type Car at address 0x108

pCar1 = &car1; // The type of the pointer matches the type of the variable, nothing special
```

Now I try to do manual address handling and I get no errors. However, the program crashes at runtime because of mismatching types.

```
pCar1 = (Car *) 0x104; // Note I am deliberately offering a Fruit address and it works without build errors
```

How can I prevent this from happening? Is there a failsafe mechanism or technique to make this stupid-proof?

Comment: What exactly do you want to prevent from happening?  The fact that the code compiles?

Comment: Nothing can prevent you from assigning whatever value you want into a pointer, 
It is your own responsibility as a programmer to validate the values that are being assigned as pointers.

Comment: C is pretty much the opposite of "stupid-proof".

Comment: Yes there were times you have to know what you do as a programmer. Today you have Java :)

Comment: If you know for a fact that address 0x104 exists in memory and you know what it points to then you cast to it. But there is no fail-safe for getting it wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> pCar1 = (Car *) 0x104;
> ```

What you're doing here is not allowed. You cannot cast an absolute address (which in your case refers to a different type) and expect it to work. In order to do this, you must be sure that an address contains the right variable type at runtime.

In this case, casting only prevents a compilation warning because it's telling the compiler "look, I know what I'm doing, trust me, there's a `Car` at this address". Of course, when your program runs and expects to find a `Car` at addres `0x104` when there isn't one, that results in undefined behavior.

> Is there a failsafe mechanism or technique to make this stupid-proof?

Absolutely not. C is very, very far from being "stupid-proof". However, the compiler would have warned you if you wrote the code in a "better way":

```
pCar1 = &fruit1; // Results in a compiler warning.
```

> How can I prevent this from happening?

Just don't do it. Don't assign random addresses or addresses of different types to variables. The only thing you can assign to `pCar1` is the address of another `Car` variable (like for example `pCar1 = &car1`) or the address of a memory location where a `Car` variable can be stored (for example the result of an appropriate `malloc()`).

---

So, in the end:

> How does pointer address type checking work?

There isn't such thing as "address type checking" in C. Only the compiler can warn you about something being of the wrong type for a certain variable, **if you give it the chance to**. Explicitly casting removes that chance.

Comment: My question was downvoted but you clearly responded to what I wanted to find out. Thanks for that.

Comment: @bem22 you're welcome. If this solved your problem you can accept my answer by clicking on the green checkmark on the top left, so that your question can be marked as solved.